# label inside box in ticklabels using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

- I need example to make customize ticklabel (label inside box), like bid price in MetaTrader platform

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put use `ax.annotate` to put a text with a bbox there.

[image]

Like:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Do the plotting

# Set the ylim for this example
ax.set(ylim=(104, 106))

# Get the xlim
right = ax.get_xlim()[1]

# Put the text
ax.annotate('105.252', (right, 105.252), (3, 0), 
            textcoords='offset points', 
            ha='left', va='center', color='w',
            bbox=dict(facecolor='#26a69a', edgecolor='none', pad=.1))
```